# React 15 - Finding offsetTop property of an element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am working on a React application which has two clickable elements. For simplicity sake, let's assume they are two buttons one of which is positioned higher than the other.

In reality there could be 30 of these buttons all positioned in a vertical list which can be scrollable as well.

```
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

<Button ref={(ref) => this.button1 = ref onClick={() => getHeight(this.button1)} }>Top</Button>
<Button ref={(ref) => this.button2 = ref onClick={() => getHeight(this.button2)}}>Bottom</Button>
```

I need to calculate the relative height between one button and another depending on which two buttons were clicked and use that to dynamically give height to a div.

The `getHeight` function looks like:

```
getHeight = (button) => {
    console.log(button.current.offsetTop);
    // In reality, it would store this y-value somewhere for this button
}
```

When running this, `undefined` is returned whenever I click a button.

In React, how do I access the `offsetTop` property of a element reference? I care about the absolute offset, not just a viewport offset. This means that when I scroll down to a button off the screen, I get the true offset from the top of the page not just what it is visually.

A few items of note:

- I am using React 15 and not 16 and do not have access to the `React.createRef` function.
- Because this is a React application, if people could suggest solutions that did not involve JQuery that would be best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, you don't exactly need ref. This can be done without that also. You can create a button and put onClick on them with the following code to calculate the absolute Y position of the buttons.

```
onClick={(e) => {this.getTop(e)}}

getTop = (e) => {
  const elem = e.target;
  const rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  const scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  const absoluteY = scrollTop + rect.top;
}
```

I have made a small fiddle example to explain to you the working of this concept. https://jsfiddle.net/7520ebgf/23/

Answer (score 1):

I think you can pass event object and then have target.offsetTop property.
Something like this:

```
  <Button onClick={e => getHeight(e.target)}>Top</Button>

 getHeight = (button) => {
   console.log(button.offsetTop);
  }
```